# Count instances of string x until string y is found

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I've been trying to do this for about an hour or so but only managed to code something that can only count or can only search. My goal is to put together something that will not only look for a specific string(let's call it "STRINGTOFIND") but also count instances of another specific(let's call it "STRINGTOCOUNT") string until it finds "STRINGTOFIND".

Here's how I count:

```
int count = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("example.xml");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String nextToken = scanner.next();
   if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase("STRINGTOCOUNT"))
   count++;
}
```

And here's how I find(I want to find it's line):

```
int lineN = 1; //set to 1 for the loop to return correct line number
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("example.xml");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    lineNum++;
    if("STRINGTOFIND".equals(scanner.nextLine().trim())) { 
        System.out.println("found on line: "+lineNum);
    }
}
```

I thought about looking for STRINGTOFIND, getting it's line number and making the first Scanner count STRINGTOCOUNT only till that line but my programming skills aren't enough for that sadly. So my question is, since I already have the code to do *only one* of the things I want to do, how do I combine these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use two if-statements in the loop.

```
boolean foundString = false;
int count = 0, lineNum = 1;
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.equals("STRINGTOFIND")){
        foundString = true;
        break; // Break out of the loop
    }
    else if(line.equals("STRINGTOCOUNT")) count++;
    lineNum++;
}
// Code that uses "foundString" and/or "lineNum"
```

This code will count the number of lines that match "STRINGTOCOUNT" until it finds a line that matches "STRINGTOFIND" or the files has no more un-read lines (lineNum will contain the line number on which this occurred).

Comment: Thanks it worked, I don't know why I couldn't think of this.